# .innerHTML does not display the html code content I need

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create text boxes dynamically using javascript, which is working fine, but when I try to use innerHTML to display the text boxes in  nothing appears on my screen.

JavaScript Code:

```
var i = 1; 
function instituteCreate(){
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("Name", "institute_" + i);
document.getElementById('userdata').innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md"><div 
class="form-group"><div class="form-field">Institute';
document.getElementById('userdata').appendChild(y);
document.getElementById('userdata').innerHTML = '</div></div></div></div>';
i++;
}
```

I have the following in my html file:

```
<div id="userdata"></div>
```

And right before the  closure I have the following which is calling the JS file:

```
<script src="js/addmore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You set `innerHTML` again right after you use `append` so the textbox is replaced by `</div></div></div></div>` thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `innerHTML` with `=` you are completely reassigning everything inside of that element overwriting everything you had before.

You can either use `+=` instead of `=` to not overwrite the value, and instead append.

Or create a template with backtick: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals